# Magento 2 wrong product price in cart after removal of category discount

Tags: php, magento2

In Magento 2 I have created a custom module **category discount**. When active its working fine for product list, details and cart view page.

But when I remove this discount it shows the original price for list and details page which is correct but **mini cart view** shows me the discounted price which shouldn't be the case. However if I update the quantity then it's fine.

I don't want to click the update button in the **mini cart view** for the original price. I want to do this using an observer.

Comment: Basically I want to do this using observer. Thanks in Advance